# ssh-add, add a private key automatically

Tags: linux, mercurial, ssh

I have a public-private ssh key pair (generated by `ssh-keygen` *without* a passphrase) and I use it with my bitbucket account, in particular with a mercurial repository.

Usually I add manually the private key in my home working pc, using `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`. I'm searching a way to do this automatically at every boot. There are many tutorials but I still have some problems.

I have tried with:

1. Add the line `ssh = ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -C` in my `~/.hgrc` mercurial settings file. This one doesn't work.
2. Create `~/.ssh/config` ssh configuration file with the following content:

   ```
   Host bitbucket-ssh
       Hostname ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/...
       IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
   ```

The second one does not work too.

What I'm wrong with? Should I use a simple bash script running `ssh-add` at every boot?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ensure that `~/.ssh/` is not group or world readable? Did you pass `-v` to `ssh` to understand what is happening?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Yes, `~/.ssh/` is `rwx------`. I did not pass -v option, I'm gonna do it now.

Comment: The files inside your `~/.ssh/` in particular `~/.ssh/id_rsa` should be readable by only you (not the group or others)

Answer (score 23):

I know this question is old, but I couldn't find the (imho) correct answer in any of the related questions.

Don't add anything to any of your shell startup scripts, this is unnecessary hackery.

Instead, add

```
AddKeysToAgent yes
```

to your .ssh/config

Like this, ssh-add is run automatically the first time you ssh into another box. You only have to re-enter your key when it expires from ssh-agent or after you reboot.

Answer (score 1):

If `ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa` solves your problem when you call it from the commandline, just add it to your `.bash_profile` (or equivalent, if you don't use bash) and be done with it. It will get run whenever you log on.